# How to get page size(Trim/Bleed/Art/Media....) in PDF with GhostScript 9.19 in windows 10?

Tags: ghostscript

I want page size (Trim/Bleed/Art/Media....) in PDF with **GS 9.19** in windows 10.

I tried this command : 
`gswin64c -dNODISPLAY -q -dDumpMediaSizes "../lib/PDFA_def.ps" test.pdf`
, but I had below error.

`Error: /undefinedfilename in --file--`

Thank you for your information.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think that pdfa_def.ps, which is used to create a PDF/A compliant PDF file would give you any information ?

I suspect you actually mean pdf_info.ps, which is located in the toolbin folder, not the lib folder.